# Consuming Razor Class UI in MVC Application

Tags: model-view-controller, razor-pages

I created a Razor Class UI Library that defines a _Layout page that works well when it is consumed from another Razor project.  (That is, a project that uses a "Pages" folder) The problem is I'd like to consume this same library from a typical MVC project (Views/Controllers/etc).  This is all Core (.NET 6.0)

The library works fine from MVC on the default route only (Home/Index).

My Program.cs file:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

However, if I navigate to Home/Page2 the page content appears but the _Layout from the class library isn't applied.  If I switch out the default route to..

```
{controller=Home}/{action=Page2}/{id?}
```

..the layout is applied as expected; however, it is no longer applied to Home/Index.

It appears the _Layout is only applied to the default MVC route.

How do I get this _Layout to be applied to all views I create in the consuming project?

I've read through several questions of this sort on StackOverflow but none of them seem to address this exact problem.  The issue isn't failing to grab the _Layout from the library, but rather, getting it to apply to more than the default route.

MORE INFO:
In a view that works the _content folder is in the expected location:
[image: Working]

For views that don't work, they appear to be looking for the _content folder in the wrong location:
[image: Not Working]